# How to create copy of NSArray and change it without affection original NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, nsarray

I need a copy of `NSArray` to store state of dates. I try to use `mytableCopy` which I understand makes copy which is independent of original object.

When I make changes to `mutableCopy` I have changes also in the original array.

Why?

My code is:

```
_nsarr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:inputArray];
_nsMraa= [NSMutableArray alloc];
_nsMraa = [_nsarr mutableCopy];
```

Note: both arrays are properties of my object. `inputArray` is input param which is not use after that.

REMARK: one object is `NSArray`, other is `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Note that the line `_nsMraa = [NSMutableArray alloc];` is doing nothing since you overwrite it in the following step.

Comment: 10x for remark @DavidBerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to by Bharat and Milan, `NSArray` is an array of reference types, it contains an array of pointers.  Calling `mutableCopy` will make a shallow copy of the array and make the copy mutable, the original will still be nonmutable.  Neither `mutableCopy` nor `copy` will perform a deep copy on the CONTENTS of the array however.  It is the ARRAY which becomes mutable or not, and not the CONTENTS of the objects held in the array.

Assuming the following:

```
@interface MyObject
- (int) state;
- (void) setState:(int) state;
@end

...

_nsarr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[MyObject alloc] initWithState]];
_nsmarr = [_nsarr mutableCopy];
```

At this point you have two distinct arrays, `_nsarr` and `_nsmarr`, one which isn't mutable, and one which is, HOWEVER, `_nsarr[0]` and `_nsmarr[0]` are still the same object, which means both that `[_nsarr[0] setState:1]` is valid, and that it has exactly the same effect as `[_nsmarr[0] setState:1]`

```
[_nsarr[0] setState:1];
NSLog("%d", [_nsmarr[0] state]);   // ==> 1

[_nsarr[0] setState:2];
NSLog("%d", [_nsmarr[0] state]);   // ==> 2
```

To copy the individual objects contained in the arrays, you need to create a "deep" copy of the array, which means to copy the contents (recursively) of the array as well as the array itself.  There is no quick and easy way to create a deep copy of an array as it largely depends on how (if?) you can make a deep copy of the referenced objects.  Bharat presents one approach (marginally costly since it serializes and deserializes the objects, and requires that they adhere to `NSCoding`)  One approach might be something like:

```
_nsmarr = [NSArray withCapacity:[_nsarr count]];
for(MyObject* foo in _nsarr) {
    [_nsmarr addObject:[foo copy]];
}
```

Assuming that foo implements the `NSCopying` protocol, this is essentially identical to the initWithArray:copyItems: approach suggested by Milan:

```
_nsmarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_nsarr copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: 10x, for detailed answer. Just what  I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
_nsMraa = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:_nsarr copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: `_nsMraa` is `NSMutableArray`. And you define it as `NSArray`. I need mutable object, so I can change state. I need non-mutable object so I can check if there are changes with the original. If I have 3 states (0,1 and 2) and I have state 2 as initial one I can change it to 0 and there will be difference, but if I change it 2 more times then it will be 2 again and there will be no difference.

Comment: Oh sorry, I somehow mis read it as NSArray, I think David answer will work for you.

Comment: 10x, for answer - I up-voted, because it is OK solution. The problem is that I receive some error. I use most "stupid" approach to add new element to new array.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a true deep copy, such as when you have an array of arrays, you can archive and then unarchive the collection, provided the contents all conform to the NSCoding protocol. An example of this technique is shown below.

- A true deep copy

  ```
  NSArray* trueDeepCopyArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:
    [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:oldArray]];
  ```